# How do I change the Background Color and Text Color in a Box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am somewhat new to Javascript/HTML. Recently I've been given a project to align boxes of Avengers characters using CSS or HTML. Here is an image of what the website should look like:

[image]

Now I've gotten the CSS part of the code done: defining the boxes for the images, headings/titles of the characters, and their description (in the main body). For the javascript part, the box of the name of the character should change color when the mouse hovers over it, and change back to its original color once removed. For this matter, I will use a portion of my code for the heading, from Iron Man.

CSS:

```
.ironManHeading { <!-- iron man's heading (goes under image box) -->
    left:0px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    function mouseIM(){ //onmouseover event: heading changes to red background and white text
        document.getElementsByClassName("ironManHeading").bgColor = 'red';
        document.getElementsByClassName("ironManHeading").fontcolor = 'white';
    } // MOUSE EVENTS FOR IRON MAN
    function noMouseIM(){ //onmouseout event: heading changes back to normal colors
        document.getElementsByClassName("ironManHeading").style.bgColor = '#999999';
        document.getElementsByClassName("ironManHeading").style.fontcolor = 'black';
    }
```

And here is the code from the body:

```
<h1 class = "ironManHeading" onmouseover = "mouseIM" onmouseout = "noMouseIM">IRON MAN</h1>
```

This is what I've tried, but the colors stay the same as from the image from above. Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something? I haven't gotten the hang of declaring classes, so I'm not sure if it's something to do with `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior with css only like this:

```
.ironManHeading:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

If you still want to use Javascript with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events here's a similar example:

```js
function onMouseOver(elem) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  elem.style.color = "white";
}

function onMouseOut(elem) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
  elem.style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="onMouseOver(this)" onmouseout="onMouseOut(this)">Here's a test</div>
```

**Why your event handlers don't work?**

It's simply because you call the methods like this:

```
onmouseover = "mouseIM"
```

but you have to call it like this:

```
onmouseover="mouseIM()"
```

that's the way to assign event handler function to a HTML event attribute.

Additionally, you can pass a reference to the object that invoked the function with:

```
onmouseover="mouseIM(this)"
```

This spares the need to use the selector of the calling element with `document.getElementById()`, `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelector()` and gives you the flexibility to use the event handler for other elements too. So in your case you can call the same function for each avenger box by calling the event handler with `this` parameter. See how I used the `elem` parameter in my event handler functions above.

Answer (score 0):

With css, you can declare a **:hover** event that does the same thing as mouseover and mouseout in javascript. Something like:

```
.ironManHeading { <!-- iron man's heading (goes under image box) -->
    /* your original definition */
}

<!-- this is the hover event -->
.ironManHeading:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Working example (does not require any javascript, everything is handled by css):

```css
.Heading {
    left:0px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.Heading:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class = "Heading">IRON MAN</h1>
<h1 class = "Heading">CAPTAIN AMAERICA</h1>
<h1 class = "Heading">THOR</h1>
<h1 class = "Heading">BLACK WIDOW</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using css pseudo-classes as @chrisbyte mentioned. In this case, you shouldn't need javascript to perform what you need, attached link below for you to learn more!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

```
.ironManHeading :hover{
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```